# Django: Increase the value in reportlab for drawstring

Tags: django, django-views, reportlab

I am using reportlab to generate pdf. Here i am retrieve profiles from database. While printing into database each and every profile should display in next page. For this i am not able to print the value while increasing the page co-ordinates.

```
def reportlab(request):

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'
    buffer = BytesIO()

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    child = Child_detail.objects.all()
    for child1 in child:
        name = child1.name
        p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
        p.drawString(500, 400, name)
        p.showPage()
        p.save()
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move the setup and saving of the canvas out of the loop, so you end up using a single instance of the Canvas

```
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
child = Child_detail.objects.all()
for child1 in child:
    name = child1.name
    p.drawString(500, 400, name)
    p.showPage()
p.save()
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i am getting one user same output only. i am not getting different full list of names.

Comment: are you sure you have more than one Child_detail record?